# Multi-Tenancy mode SCHEMA in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Environment:

- Grails v5.3.2
- PostgreSQL 14.0
- OpenJDK 11.0.12

I use Grails 5.3.2 to develop a multi-tenancy web application. In this web application, I use SCHEMA as my multi-tenancy mode. According to my understand, multi-tenancy with mode SCHEMA means that each assigned schema will have the same tables. But I can not make it.

Below are the key points of relevant files.

**application.yml**

```
---
grails:
    profile: vue
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: worker.order
    gorm:
        failOnError: true
        reactor:
            events: false
        multiTenancy:
            mode: SCHEMA 
            tenantResolverClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.web.SessionTenantResolver
 ....
 ....
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''

environments:
    development:
        logging:
            config: classpath:logback-dev.xml
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            schemaHandler: com.workerorder.utils.MySchemaHandler
            driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/workerorder
            username: 'foo'
            password: 'foo'
```

**MySchemaHandler.groovy**

```
package com.workerorder.utils

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.schema.SchemaHandler

import javax.sql.DataSource
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement

@Slf4j
class MySchemaHandler implements SchemaHandler {
    private List<String> existedSchemaList = []
    private static List<String> TARGET_SCHEMA_LIST = ['cx_david', 'cx_john']
    @Override
    Collection<String> resolveSchemaNames(DataSource dataSource) {
        log.info("resolveSchemaNames(): ENTER .....")
        return  TARGET_SCHEMA_LIST
    }

    @Override
    void useSchema(Connection connection, String name) {
        String lowerCaseSchemaName = name.toLowerCase()
        log.info("useSchema(): name: {} ==> {}", name, lowerCaseSchemaName)
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("""
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM information_schema.schemata
   WHERE schema_name = '${lowerCaseSchemaName}'
) as schema_exist;
""")
        rs.next()
        boolean schemaExist = rs.getBoolean("schema_exist")
        log.info("useSchema(): schema {} exists? {}", lowerCaseSchemaName, schemaExist)
        if (!schemaExist) throw new SQLException("schema [${lowerCaseSchemaName}] not exists")
        connection.createStatement().execute("set search_path = ${lowerCaseSchemaName}")

    }

    @Override
    void useDefaultSchema(Connection connection) {
        log.info("useDefaultSchema(): ENTER ...........")
        connection.createStatement().execute("set search_path = public")
    }

    @Override
    void createSchema(Connection connection, String name) {
        String lowerCaseSchemaName = name.toLowerCase()
        log.info("createSchema(): name: {} =>{}", name, lowerCaseSchemaName)
        Statement createSchemaStmt =  connection.createStatement()
        String sql = "create schema ${lowerCaseSchemaName} "
        boolean rc = createSchemaStmt.execute(sql)
    }
}
```

**domain: TUser**

```
package com.workerorder.domain

class TUser implements MultiTenant<TUser> {
    String userid
    static mapping = {
        id name:'userid', generator:'assigned'
    }
    static constraints = {
        userid      maxSize: 20
    }
}
```

**TestController**

```
package com.workerorder.controller

import com.workerorder.domain.TUser
import grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants
import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.schema.DefaultSchemaHandler
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.schema.SchemaHandler
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.AllTenantsResolver
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.web.SessionTenantResolver
/**
 * http://localhost:8080/test
 */
class TestController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def index() {

        saveTUser('alexji', 'cx_mary')
        render "TEST DONE"
    }
    private void saveTUser(String userid, String schemaName) {
        log.info("save user {} to schema {}", userid, schemaName)
        session[SessionTenantResolver.ATTRIBUTE] = schemaName
        Tenants.withId(schemaName) {
            TUser tUser = new TUser(userid: userid)
            TUser.withTransaction {
                tUser.save()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this web starts, the logs are below:

```
|Running application...
2023-05-20 07:54:22.920  INFO --- [  restartedMain] Application                : The following 1 profile is active: "development"
2023-05-20 07:54:26.488  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : resolveSchemaNames(): ENTER .....
2023-05-20 07:54:26.498  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : =========================================
2023-05-20 07:54:26.503 DEBUG --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : resolveSchemaNames(): schema: information_schema
2023-05-20 07:54:26.503 DEBUG --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : resolveSchemaNames(): schema: pg_catalog
2023-05-20 07:54:26.503 DEBUG --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : resolveSchemaNames(): schema: public
2023-05-20 07:54:26.504  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : resolveSchemaNames(): existedSchemaList: []
2023-05-20 07:54:26.510  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): name: cx_david ==> cx_david
2023-05-20 07:54:26.515  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): schema cx_david exists? false
2023-05-20 07:54:26.517  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : createSchema(): name: cx_david =>cx_david
2023-05-20 07:54:26.520  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useDefaultSchema(): ENTER ...........
2023-05-20 07:54:26.532  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): name: cx_david ==> cx_david
2023-05-20 07:54:26.534  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): schema cx_david exists? true
2023-05-20 07:54:26.541  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useDefaultSchema(): ENTER ...........
2023-05-20 07:54:26.552  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): name: cx_john ==> cx_john
2023-05-20 07:54:26.554  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): schema cx_john exists? false
2023-05-20 07:54:26.554  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : createSchema(): name: cx_john =>cx_john
2023-05-20 07:54:26.557  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useDefaultSchema(): ENTER ...........
2023-05-20 07:54:26.567  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): name: cx_john ==> cx_john
2023-05-20 07:54:26.569  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useSchema(): schema cx_john exists? true
2023-05-20 07:54:26.573  INFO --- [  restartedMain] MySchemaHandler            : useDefaultSchema(): ENTER ...........
2023-05-20 07:54:28.514  INFO --- [  restartedMain] Application                : Started Application in 6.282 seconds (JVM running for 7.276)
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
```

At this moment, in PostgreSQL, I confirm the above two schemas were just created.

```
workerorder=> SELECT schema_name
FROM information_schema.schemata;
    schema_name
--------------------
 pg_catalog
 public
 information_schema
 cx_david
 cx_john
(5 rows)

workerorder=> \dt *.tuser;
         List of relations
  Schema  | Name  | Type  |  Owner  
----------+-------+-------+---------
 cx_david | tuser | table | appuser
 cx_john  | tuser | table | appuser
 public   | tuser | table | appuser
(3 rows)
```

Now I use `TestController` to simulate dynamically adding a schema `cx_mary`. When I execute `http://localhost:8080/test`, below exception happens:

```
2023-05-21 19:32:17.040  INFO --- [nio-8080-exec-2] TestController             : save user alexji to schema cx_mary
2023-05-21 19:32:17.058 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-2] StackTrace                 : Full Stack Trace:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.exceptions.ConfigurationException: DataSource not found for name [cx_mary] in configuration. Please check your multiple data sources configuration and try again.
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.getDatastoreForConnection(HibernateDatastore.java:359)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.getDatastoreForConnection(HibernateDatastore.java:85)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore.withNewSession(AbstractHibernateDatastore.java:366)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2.doCall(Tenants.groovy:258)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2.call(Tenants.groovy)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$CurrentTenant.withTenant(Tenants.groovy:358)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.withId(Tenants.groovy:236)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.withId(Tenants.groovy:169)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$withId.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at com.workerorder.controller.TestController.saveTUser(TestController.groovy:25)
    at com.workerorder.controller.TestController.index(TestController.groovy:19)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

My questions is:

1. At the runtime of Grails, how to add a new schema and how to let Grails dynamically duplicate all tables (ex: `tuser` in this case) in the new-created schema ?